# Build OpenConnect on 14.04 with PKCS#11 support

Tags: openconnect

I'm trying to build *OpenConnect 7.07* on *Ubuntu 14.04* using autobuild shell script from

[GitHub Autobuild script for OpenConnect 7 (Ubuntu 14/15/16 trusty/vivid/xenial)](https://gist.github.com/darrenpmeyer/b0b964e02f815be75698)

The build works, but when I try to connect to Juniper VPN, I get an error '*This version of OpenConnect was built without PKCS#11 support*'. The command and output are as follows (actual pkcs11 params and URL have been replaced, but that does not affect the error):

```
$ sudo openconnect --juniper --no-cert-check -c 'pkcs11:MY_PARAMS' example.com
WARNING: Juniper Network Connect support is experimental.
It will probably be superseded by Junos Pulse support.
GET https://example.com/
Connected to 93.184.216.34:443
This version of OpenConnect was built without PKCS#11 support
Loading certificate failed. Aborting.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to example.com
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

Does anyone know, what should I do so that OpenConnect build would support PKCS#11?

Remarks:

- [Building OpenConnect by Infradead.org](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/building.html) mentions *p11-kit* (for PKCS#11 support) and *libp11* (also needed for PKCS#11 support if using OpenSSL). Before building I installed *p11-kit (0.20.2-2ubunt)* and *libudev-dev (204-5ubuntu)* - this had no effect.
- I tried to run `./configure` with and without *--without-gnutls* flag, error remained unchanged.

**EDIT:**
The suggestion in the comment by @steeldriver worked.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libp11-kit-dev libp11-dev
```

After rebuilding and running OpenConnect, PKCS#11 support error was not there any more.

Comment: The development packages seem to be [libp11-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libp11-dev) and [libp11-kit-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libp11-kit-dev)

Comment: @steeldriver your suggestion worked, the PKCS#11 error is not there any more. How did you figure out these were the packages required?

Comment: I just did `apt-cache search dev | grep -i pkcs` and looked for the most likely candidates based on the package description